# How to make EditText editable after I drag

Tags: android

I am creating a draggable editText, I used editText to allow user to change the text. But my problem now is I cannot edit the text anymore because it detects the touch/dragging of the text.

Any solution for this?

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
              DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);
              view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
              view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                    break;
        }
    return true;
    }

}
```

and I have drag listener

```
  class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    @Override
      public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
         paramsBlock = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(), view.getWidth());  
          paramsBlock.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - (view.getWidth()/2);//- ((imageView.getWidth()/9)/2);
          paramsBlock.topMargin = (int) event.getY() -(view.getHeight()/2);//-((imageView.getWidth()/9)/2);

          view.setLayoutParams(paramsBlock);             
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
          default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }
  }
```

Is it possible to use `onLongClick` Listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `onLongClickListener` to start the drag. This should allow you to edit the field because the control's default click or touch listener won't be overridden

Try something like this for your drag initiation

```
OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return true;
    }
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad that I could be of help

Comment: can you help me to solve this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922299/click-zone-of-edittext-is-getting-bigger-after-dragging

Comment: How to put drop image after dragging?

Comment: You will have to use the listeners to know when to show a drop image

Comment: how to drop the image?