# Click zone of EditText is getting bigger after dragging

Tags: android

I am creating a draggable editText, my problem now is the click zone of the edit text is getting bigger after I drag the edit text, so I cannot select other objects because the click zone of the editText is bigger.

for example:

```
+-------------+
|             |
|             |
|  Text Here  |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

I tried to set background to black just to check the width of editText.

This is my xml file:

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.21" 
        android:id="@+id/imgstage"
        android:tag="stage">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tap" />

                 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtAddText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:text="Tap here to change text"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and this my listener for editText:

```
    class longClickTextListener implements OnLongClickListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find that the EditText width is being adjusted by setting the background color to black? Or is it still the same size as before the drag?

Comment: The editText before dragging is just like 1 line but after dragging it gets bigger.